# Ordering Months within Pivot SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to do a PIVOT based on months and years. I always get stuck with pivots in general. Trying to order the months from January to December but it is always starting from December to January after the year column. Here is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT PvtMonth.TYear,
       PvtMonth.December,
       PvtMonth.November,
       PvtMonth.October,
       PvtMonth.September,
       PvtMonth.August,
       PvtMonth.July,
       PvtMonth.June,
       PvtMonth.May,
       PvtMonth.April,
       PvtMonth.March,
       PvtMonth.February,
       PvtMonth.January
FROM
(
SELECT DATENAME(YEAR, InvoiceDate) AS TYear,DATENAME(MONTH, InvoiceDate) AS TMonth, TrackingNo
FROM [MSM14].[dbo].[PVH_Global_Dash]
WHERE ReceiverAddress LIKE '%78 Mccullough%'
) AS P1
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(TrackingNo)
FOR TMonth IN
(
        [January],
        [February],
        [March],
        [April],
        [May],
        [June],
        [July],
        [August],
        [September],
        [October],
        [November],
        [December]
)) AS PvtMonth
```

Comment: *"it is always starting from December to January"* Well yes, that's what you've defined... `SELECT ... December, November, October..., January`. If you want January first, list it first in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT YEAR(InvoiceDate) AS TYear,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(InvoiceDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Jan,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(InvoiceDate) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Feb,
       . . . 
FROM [MSM14].[dbo].[PVH_Global_Dash]
WHERE ReceiverAddress LIKE '%78 Mccullough%' AND
      TrackingNo IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(InvoiceDate);
```

The condition `TrackingNo IS NOT NULL` may not be necessary, but your version is counting non-`NULL` values.  If it is never `NULL` just remove the condition.